# MVC Identity 2 - HasBeenVerifiedAsync FAIL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am sure you have all see the code below:

```
 Public Async Function VerifyCode(provider As String, returnUrl As String, rememberMe As Boolean, email As String) As Task(Of ActionResult)
        ' Require that the user has already logged in via username/password or external login
        If Not Await SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync() Then
            Return View("Error")
        End If
        Return View(New VerifyCodeViewModel() With {
            .Provider = provider,
            .ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
            .RememberMe = rememberMe, .Email = email
        })
    End Function
```

When i log into the site for the first time the `HasBeenVerifiedAsync` indicates that the user is NOT logged in. If i log out then log back in it passes as TRUE.

Any idea why this is happening seems like a bug....  I assume it is checking for token... which looks like is coming down through fiddler...